# The type or namespace name 'Speech' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

[!][1]][1][[image: засада]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3zP1.png)подскажите пожалуйста что происходит вчера студия переваривала System.Speech.Recognition а сегодня ни в какую. Microsoft.Speech.dll загружен и подключен. работаю в консольном.

Comment: Наверно надо опубликовать чего она пишет, угадывать некогда :)

Comment: дык то что в заголовке есть то и пишет.

Comment: обидно что вчера еще всё красиво собиралось.

Comment: А вы режим сборки по процессору не меняли? Или версию NET ? Попробуйте удалить библиотеку в ссылках, сохранить, перезагрузить и снова добавить. Иногда помогает создать проект с нуля. Ещё есть app.config, там тоже могут быть настройки сборок, осмотрите его внимательно. И у вас на картинке 2 длл, попробуйте добавить родную, не с сдк.

Comment: что значит родную?

Comment: Которая по умолчанию в директории Виндовз а не сдк.

Comment: дохлый номер. как-то уже было что то похожее но в другом неймспейс , после переустановки винды заработало.

Answer (score 1):

ответ прост: по невнимательности я использовал 
using System.Speech.Recognition;   ....
а нужно было
using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/313453)

Comment: Обычно имена библиотек называют в соответствии с их пространствами имен, поэтому не удивительно что `System.Speech` не бралось из `Microsoft.Speech.dll`.

Comment: @freim, вроде бы вполне ответ.